# Помогите с запросом sql новичку

Tags: c#, sql

Имеется таблица получаемая запросом `string query = "SELECT * FROM oc_product";`
в ней не хватает названий товаров но есть id

Есть другая таблица oc_product_description где есть названия товаров в столбце name и их id

Как составить запрос так чтоб вернулась вся таблица oc_product + названия товаров с таблицы oc_product_description?
понимаю что сравнить их по id но как это сделать в запросе?

Comment: Какой Sql? Ms Sql? My Sql? Sql с драконом? Выражайся яснее. Какой Sql? (с)

Comment: MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con); база на хостинге (если это важно)

Comment: я перечитал ваш вопрос, и немного не понял. Зачем вам id товара держать отдельно от имени товара? где вы после хотите все выводить по id? Не проще иметь одну таблицу с id name_product product_description.

Comment: это движек опенкарт так держит я же пытаюсь научится собирать то что разбросано, суть в науке а база какая уж есть

Comment: SELECT oc_product.*, oc_product_description.* FROM oc_product, oc_product_description WHERE oc_product.id = oc_product_description.id ? Мб что-то типа такого?

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если всё так просто, как я понял, то нужно всего лишь включить вторую таблицу в запрос и взять из неё имена.

```
SELECT op.id, opd.name FROM oc_product op
JOIN oc_product_description opd ON opd.id = op.id
```

Дальнейшее уже зависит от условий, нужно ли взять какие-то особые id, существуют ли все id из первой таблицы во второй и т.п.

Comment: можно узнать что такое opd и op? полагаю их можно заменить на oc_product_description и oc_product? потому что в таком виде не работает

Comment: @СергейПрограмирович короткие обозначения таблиц, так как запросы бывают довольно большими, писать их в стиле ```SELECT oc_product_description.id, oc_product_description.name, oc_product_description.price...``` будет неудобно и громоздко. Для сокращения и удобства таблицам в запросе можно дать короткие имена, например ```FROM oc_product AS op``` или просто ```FROM oc_product op```, оператор ```AS``` в данном случае можно опустить и задать короткое имя через пробел после полного.

Comment: @СергейПрограмирович, да, можно их убрать и сделать запрос ```SELECT oc_product.id, oc_product_description.name FROM oc_product
JOIN oc_product_description ON oc_product_description.id = oc_product.id```